# Code Blocks with WYSIWYG in blog post

Tags: posts, formatting

Is it possible to format code in the wysiwyg editor, up to now I use Blockquotes to represent code, but my problem is that it does automatically line breaks, and I don't want to have random line breaks in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to deal with this problem.

You could have a look for some syntax highlighter plugin, those will also bring you coloured text with highlighted keywords etc. pp. This is probably nice, if you use code quite often. I use [SyntaxHighlighter Evolved](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/).

If you want to do this by hand, `<code>` is probably the HTML-element you want to use, just like Stack Overflow does, too. It´s "designed" to be used that way (and understood as code from a semantical view, too).

If you want to prevent line breaks, you can add this to your CSS:

```
code { white-space: nowrap; }
```

You have to use this in the text view of the editor though, as the WYSIWYG version would probably strap it out.

You can get around that by defining a shortcode for your code-tag. You will find lots of examples for that around the web.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you provide a syntax highlighter plugin that matches my requirements?

Comment: I updated my post, there you´ll find a link to SyntaxHighlighter Evolved, that´s the plugin I use.